# How to clear a notification in Android

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to clear a notification programatically?

I tried it with the `NotificationManager` but its not working.
Is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: It is possible to clear your own notifications but not anyone else's

Comment: Yes agree with Donal for piece of code see http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/removing-status-bar-notification-from.html

Comment: See this answer for a way to clear other notifications for API>=18 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25693210/1073832

Answer (score 250):

Use the following code to cancel a Notification:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

In this code, there is always the same `ID` used for notifications. If you have different notifications that need to be canceled, you have to save the ids that you used to create the Notification.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't upvoted more and selected as the answer. This was the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: What should be the notification id here?

Comment: This indeed works. But once I cancel a notification, all subsequent notifications do not show the notification message text (which I set using `setContentText`) though I set the priority to 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not working if notification flag set as Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR

Comment: for all and if you dont know which id,  if (notificationManager != null) {
                        notificationManager.cancelAll();
                    }

Comment: @Deepak To create the notification, you probably did something like `NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, ...)`. The `NOTIFICATION_ID` that you passed as first parameter to the `notify` method is the same as the `NOTIFICATION_ID` that you should pass to `notificationManager.cancel`.

Answer (score 44):

From:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

> To clear the status bar notification when the user selects it from the Notifications window, add the "FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL" flag to your Notification object. You can also clear it manually with cancel(int), passing it the notification ID, or clear all your Notifications with cancelAll().

But Donal is right, you can only clear notifications that you created.

Comment: This will not cancel a Notification programatically.

Comment: not sure what Janusz is talking about but cancel(id) and cancelAll() certainly work

Answer (score 35):

Since no one has posted a code answer to this:

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

.. and if you already have flags, you can OR FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL like this:

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: It's better this way: `notifcation.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`

Comment: Could anyone explain why it's better that way?

Comment: @Prof It's less code for the same purpose, and has no impact on the performance.

Comment: @Denny This assumes the first notification flag is defined above so it's two lines instead of the one line

Answer (score 29):

Please try methods provided in [NotificationManagerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat#cancelAll()).

To remove all notifications,

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancelAll();
```

To remove a particular notification,

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(notificationId);
```

Comment: In case anyone is getting stuck on NotificationManager not having a `cancel` method, the `cancel` method is not static, so you need an instance of `NotificationManager` like this: `NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`
Then you can call `notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);` like Rohit Suthar referenced in his answer.
`notificationId` is simply the ID you passed into `notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mNotification)`

Answer (score 8):

Starting with API level 18 (Jellybean MR2) you can cancel Notifications other than your own via  NotificationListenerService.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {...}
```

...

```
private void clearNotificationExample(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    myNotificationListenerService.cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are generating Notification from a Service that is started in the foreground using

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Then issuing

```
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

does not end up canceling the Notification, and the notification still appears in the status bar. In this particular case, you will need to issue

```
stopForeground( true );
```

from within the service to put it back into background mode and to simultaneously cancel the notifications. Alternately, you can push it into the background without having it cancel the notification and then cancel the notification.

```
stopForeground( false );
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)

                .setContentTitle("A message from: " + fromUser)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
```

**.setAutoCancel(true)**

when you click on notification, open corresponding activity and remove notification from notification bar

Answer (score 6):

I believe the most **RECENT** and **UPDATED** for AndroidX and backward compatibility. The best way of doing (Kotlin and Java) this should be done as:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)
```

Or to cancel all notifications is:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancelAll()
```

Made for AndroidX or Support Libraries.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `NotificationCompat.Builder` (a part of `android.support.v4`) then simply call its object's method `setAutoCancel`

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Some guys were reporting that `setAutoCancel()` did not work for them, so you may try this way as well

```
builder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Note that **the method `getNotification()` has been deprecated**!!!

Comment: The question asked how to clear it programmatically. setAutoCancel() clears it when the user clicks on the Notification. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)

Comment: @SFitz It's not clear from the question what he wants. I understood that he wants to clear notification when a user clicks on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions
    // >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);
    builder.setSound(soundUri);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

this works if you are using a notification builder...

Answer (score 1):

```
   String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
  NotificationManager Nmang = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                                                     .getSystemService(ns);
  Nmang .cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("notificationID"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually as answered before starting with API Level 18 you can cancel Notifications posted by other apps differet than your own using NotificationListenerService but that approach will no longer work on Lollipop, here is the way to remove notifications covering also Lillipop API.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
}
else {
    cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
}
```

Comment: I cannot find the method `cancelNotification` what is it?

Comment: It is a method from NotificationListenerService class, please check the official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Comment: How can I use it outside of the the service?

Answer (score 0):

All notifications (even other app notifications) can be removed via listening to 'NotificationListenerService' as mentioned in [NotificationListenerService Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation)

In the service you have to call `cancelAllNotifications()`.

The service has to be enabled for your application via:

‘Apps & notifications’ -> ‘Special app access’ -> ‘Notifications access’.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me:

```
public class ExampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    int notificationId = 1;
    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function written in **Kotlin**:

```
/**
 * Delete the notification
 */
fun delete(context: Context, notificationId: Int) =
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        cancel(notificationId)
    }
```

Or shorter:

```
fun delete(context: Context, notificationId: Int) = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(notificationId)
```

Answer (score 0):

**To clear notifications on Oreo and greater versions**

```
//Create Notification
     Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
    
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                createNotificationChannel(builder, notificationManager);
                mNotificationManager=notificationManager;
                startForeground(1, notification);


    //Remove notification
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use OneSignal, you must use one of this:

Specific notification:

```
OneSignal.removeNotification(mutableNotification.androidNotificationId)
```

All notifications:

```
OneSignal.clearOneSignalNotifications()
```

In OneSignal's java doc says:

For removeNotification

```
Cancels a single OneSignal notification based on its Android notification integer ID. Use
* instead of Android's {@link NotificationManager#cancel(int)}, otherwise the notification will be restored
* when your app is restarted.
```

For clearOneSignalNotifications

```
If you just use
* {@link NotificationManager#cancelAll()}, OneSignal notifications will be restored when
* your app is restarted.
```