# How to get button event for Android Notification panel?

Tags: android, notifications

any one have idea how to get button notification from Notification panel.

I added an button in custom notification panel layout, but i not able to get events for this added button,means here I want two different events, one for panel and another one for added button.

pls suggest me how can i do this.

Comment: This link will help you do it
Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396318/adding-onclick-action-to-button-in-notification)!

Comment: Thanks Syed...will give it look... also appreciated for 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications

Answer (score 0):

may be this helps

[Event OnClick for a button in a custom notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479165/event-onclick-for-a-button-in-a-custom-notification)