# Calling a simple method on button click from a notification created within a service

Tags: android

I'm trying to call a simple method (not an activity) from a button in a notification. The button may be either created using .addAction or perhaps using RemoteViews.

The notification is created within a Service.

I've tried reading similar questions [Handling buttons inside android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications) and trying what was suggested there to no avail.  Does anyone have a complete solution for creating such a notification?  Does the fact that the notification is being created from a service rather than an activity cause any issues?

Thanks.

Comment: "I'm trying to call a simple method (not an activity) from a button in a notification" -- a `Notification`, whether using `RemoteViews` or other facilities, only executes a `PendingIntent`. With a `PendingIntent`, you can start an activity, start a service, or send a broadcast. You cannot "call a simple method". "and trying what was suggested there to no avail" -- that is a useless description of your symptoms.

Comment: Agreed - the solution others proposed was to send a broadcast, and have a broadcast receiver which will do whatever it is I want to do.  I tried these solutions but nothing happens - the broadcast receiver never gets the broadcast - so I assume it is not sent or not sent correctly.

Comment: And without being able to see any of your code, it is impossible for people to help you.

Comment: I was trying to use a Broadcast intent but instead got it working with a Service.