# Adding onClick Action To Button In Notification

Tags: android, button, notifications, onclicklistener

I'm trying to add button to Notification using custom layout. I was able to add the layout and display the button. However, I still can't figure out a way to add click listener to the button. Here is the relevant code I have:

**Codes to add custom layout notification:**

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
CharSequence tickerText = "Quick Application Launcher";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx);
Notification notification=builder.getNotification();
notification.when=when;
notification.tickerText=tickerText;
notification.icon=R.drawable.ic_launcher;

RemoteViews contentView=new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);

Intent volume=new Intent(ctx, NotifActivityHandler.class);
volume.putExtra("DO", "2");
PendingIntent pVolume = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, volume, 0);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn2, pVolume);

notification.contentView = contentView;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
mNotificationManager.notify(2345345, notification);
```

**This is the NotifActivityHandler code:**

```
public class NotifActivityHandler extends Activity {

    private NotifActivityHandler ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx=this;
        String action= (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");
        Log.i("LOG", "lauching action: " + action);
        if(action.equals("1")){
        } else if(action.equals("2")){
        } else if(action.equals("config")){
            Intent i = new Intent(NotifActivityHandler.this, ConfigActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }   
}
```

Codes above doesn't produce any log even if I put `Log.i`. I'm not sure what is wrong with this. Any help is appreciated.

**update**

I tested this on ICS device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to register your listner in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications)

Comment: you are right, I forgot to register my `NotifActivityHandler` listener :(

Comment: What if I do not want to launch activity on click of button I just want to take simple action.for example pause the song.