# Notifications Cancel Button in android

Tags: android, notifications

[image: There is a croos button in notification, how to add that??]

the screenshot contains notifications from two different applications.
in the upper notification , there is a cancel button, How to add that  button in notification.
Any help will be extremely thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Custom Notification Layout as outlined in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification).

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to create a notification with a custom layout (view [here](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/#Custom_View)) how to do that. You can attach a click listener with a pending intent to a button like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396318/adding-onclick-action-to-button-in-notification).