# Android how to resume and pause audio from notification bar without open app?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to implement resume and pause function running music in the background from notification bar. In my code I am using radio play from url downloaded from server. And then play audio in background. But i want to add functionality to play and pause function without open application. Thank you.

Comment: You need to handle the click event  in the Notification bar, Please check the notificationCombat in android.

Comment: have you any example?

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/
Please check the link it will working example you need to customize it based on your requirement.

Comment: i also used this. but when i click on notification it opens activity which we intent. i want both.

Comment: You need to check how to control background service from the notification

Comment: ya i know. but first i need click event. after that i know what i have to do.

Comment: can you please check the addAction option in the android document

Comment: ya it also open an activity.

Answer (score 1):

already asked:

[Handling buttons inside android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications)

[Adding onClick Action To Button In Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396318/adding-onclick-action-to-button-in-notification)

doesn't have enough reputations to add these links as a comment

Comment: it's the only way to work with clicks on notification views. You create PendingIntent and assign this intent to remoteView like this: `notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonswitch, pendingSwitchIntent);`

Comment: yaeh i do. but i want both . open activity and also start stop funcation like our phone music player. understand?

Comment: no problems, just add another pending intent to parent view

Comment: like. just for an example

Comment: I was wrong, it's not necessary to add pendingintent to parent view, simply setContentIntent for notification builder and you will start activity clicking the whole notification. About child views: I've tried the first example and have no succes until register Broadcast receiver in Manifest. Does it help you, @Das ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88382/discussion-between-yazazzello-and-das).