# Android notification with buttons on it

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to make a notification with 2 buttons on it:

- one takes me back to the activity
- the other closes it

Has anyone got an idea on how to catch the button click event (remember that the Activity is paused)?

Comment: To be honest i don't like the idea behind your efford, or i do not understand it. Normal notifications in android have the X on the right side and if you click on them you a redirected to the activity.

Comment: We teach them and show them the Android Developer Guidelines ;)

Answer (score 44):

I am glad to post it! After working all night I found something. So, here we go!

**1. Create an xml layout file for your notification.**

**2. Create the notification using the Notification.Builder. After adding everything you want (icons, sounds, etc) do this:**

```
        //R.layout.notification_layout is from step 1

        RemoteViews contentView=new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

        setListeners(contentView);//look at step 3

        notification.contentView = contentView;
```

**3. Create a method setListeners. Inside this method you have to write this:**

```
    //HelperActivity will be shown at step 4

    Intent radio=new Intent(ctx, packagename.youractivity.class);  
    radio.putExtra("AN_ACTION", "do");//if necessary

    PendingIntent pRadio = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, radio, 0);
    //R.id.radio is a button from the layout which is created at step 2  view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radio, pRadio); 

    //Follows exactly my code!
    Intent volume=new Intent(ctx, tsapalos11598712.bill3050.shortcuts.helper.HelperActivity.class);
    volume.putExtra("DO", "volume");</p>

    //HERE is the whole trick. Look at pVolume. I used 1 instead of 0.
    PendingIntent pVolume = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, volume, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.volume, pVolume);
```

**4. For my requirements I used a HelperActivity which responds to the intents. But for you I don't think it is necessary.**

If you want the full source code you can browse it or download it from my git repo. The code is for personal use, so don't expect to read a gorgeous code with a lot of comments. https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/AndroidProject_Shortcuts

ALL THE ABOVE, ANSWERS THE QUESTION OF CATCHING EVENT FROM DIFFERENT BUTTONS.

About canceling the notification I redirect you here

[How to clear a notification in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

Just remember to use the id you parsed at the notify method when you called the notification for fist time

Comment: This works brilliantly on ICS 4.0.4! You should consider formatting your answer properly so that other users can have a good look at your answer.

Comment: You are right. I should have done it from the beggining. I hope that it is better now. Due to your comment I added the link to download the source code. All the readers from now on should thank you, not me. Happy ending year and Happiest new year

Comment: That's nice of you! Happy New Year!!

Answer (score 5):

There is a full example for you here

```
    //Add this code to onCreate or some onclick Buttton
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), notificationActivity.class).putExtra("notification", "1");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notification.when = when;

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_view);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvName, "New Name");
    listener(remoteViews,getApplicationContext());


    notification.contentView = remoteViews;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    manager.notify(1, notification);
```

and then you can define listener method :

```
    public void listener(RemoteViews remoteViews, Context context) {
    // you have to make intetns for each action (your Buttons)
    Intent intent = new Intent("Accept");
    Intent intent2 = new Intent("Reject");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,intent,0);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,intent2,0);

    // add actions here !
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("Accept");
    intentFilter.addAction("Reject");


    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals("Accept")){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Accepted !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(intent.getAction().equals("Reject")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Rejected !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    context.registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivRequest,pendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivReject,pendingIntent2);

}
```

and here is the notification_view layout to costumize your notification .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Request from "
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
    android:text="Amin"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivRequest"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/notification"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivReject"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ivRequest"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/trash"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This example does what it claims with a copy & paste (after you add your drawables).  However, `builder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews);` would be better than `notification.contentView = remoteViews;` and `builder.build()` is better than `builder.getNotification()` due to deprecations.  (You have to rearrange the code a bit for these changes).

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from my own SimpleProject 
and Thanks for the updates :)

Answer (score 4):

As for ICS, the question is simple to reply because the required behaviour reflects default notification: you can **close** a notification swiping it to the right, and you can define which **activity** to send the user to when he presses it simply using `PendingIntent`:

```
// The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
// notification.  Note the use of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT so that, if there
// is already an active matching pending intent, cancel it and replace
// it with the new array of Intents.
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0,
        makeMessageIntentStack(this, from, message), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

code taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, although it's not what i asked..
What I wanna do is a notification with 2 buttons on it (already have the layout), but I'm having problems catching the onClick event, I want one of them to close the **ACTIVITY** and the other to make the default action of the notification.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign specific intent to a button:

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_button_id, pendingIntent);
```

I suppose that you need only one intent to be sent when the button is clicked, so you have to AVOID setting the main notification intent

```
notification.contentIntent = yourPendingIntent;
```

Otherwise (if you set "notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;" as usual) both intents will be called which might not be what you want/user expects.

If you still want pressing other parts of the notification invoke that general intent (or any other) you can use the same method of intent-per-view assignment as above. Don't forget to set

```
android:clickable="true"
```

to any view you'd like to track onClick() for.

You can track these intents by their extras in the activity they are calling. **If** you are **calling you main/launcher activity** than you'll track them here (as it comes from javadoc for this method):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();

    if (data != null && data.containsKey(YOUR_INTENT_KEY_SOURCE_CONSTANT)) {
       // process your notification intent
    }

    // go on with smth else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add action Buttons in your `Notification` by setting action  to your `Notification.Builder` and defining `PendingIntent` for each action

below is the sample code:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
       .addAction(R.drawable.action_posetive,"posetive",PendingIntent.getActivity(0,intent,0))
.addAction(R.drawable.action_clear,"clear",PendingIntent.getActivity(0,intent,0));
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is working greatly..
I will write down the whole example..
**This is for Notification create**

```
public void createNotification2(String aMessage) {
    final int NOTIFY_ID = 11;
    String name = getString(R.string.app_name);
    String id = getString(R.string.app_name); // The user-visible name of the channel.
    String description = getString(R.string.app_name); // The user-visible description of the channel.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    if (notifManager == null) {
        notifManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
        if (mChannel == null) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(description);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    } else {

    }
    Intent Off_broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, Database_Update.class);
    Off_broadcastIntent.setAction("on");
    Off_broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", "1");
    PendingIntent Off_actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, Off_broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent on_broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, Database_Update.class);
    on_broadcastIntent.setAction("off");
    on_broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", "0");
    PendingIntent on_actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, on_broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent cancel_broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, Database_Update.class);
    cancel_broadcastIntent.setAction("cancel");
    cancel_broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", "close");
    PendingIntent cancel_actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, cancel_broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent content_intent = new Intent(this, Status_Page.class);
    content_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, content_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
            .addAction(R.drawable.block, "ON", Off_actionIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.notification, "OFF", on_actionIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.clear, "CLOSE", cancel_actionIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR|Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notifManager.notify(11, notification);
}
```

**In Android Menifest**

```
<service android:name=".Database_Update"></service>
```

**This is service class**

```
public class Database_Update extends Service {
String result="";

Realm realm;
BlockList blockList;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    try {
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("notification.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("SERVICE","SERVICE CHECKING");
    result=intent.getStringExtra("toastMessage");
    Log.d("SERVICE",result);
    if (realm!=null){
        Log.d("SERVICE","realm working");
    }else {
        Log.d("SERVICE","Realm not working");
    }
    blockList=realm.where(BlockList.class).equalTo("package_name", "BLOCK_ALL").findFirst();
    try {
        Log.d("SERVICE",blockList.getStatus());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    realm.beginTransaction();
    if (result.equals("1")){
        if (blockList==null){
            BlockList blockList_new=realm.createObject(BlockList.class);
            blockList_new.setPackage_name("BLOCK_ALL");
            blockList_new.setStatus("yes");
        }else {
            blockList.setStatus("yes");
        }
        Log.d("SERVICE","BLOCKING NOTIFICATION");
        Toast.makeText(this, "BLOCKING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (result.equals("0")){
        if (blockList==null){
            BlockList blockList_new=realm.createObject(BlockList.class);
            blockList_new.setPackage_name("BLOCK_ALL");
            blockList_new.setStatus("no");
        }else {
            blockList.setStatus("no");
        }
        Log.d("SERVICE","ALLOW NOTIFICATION");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ALLOW NOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (result.equals("close")){
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(11);
        Log.d("SERVICE","REMOVING");
        Toast.makeText(this, "CLOSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (realm!=null){
        realm.close();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "REMOVING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```