# Notifications with buttons, possible on Froyo+?

Tags: android, button, notifications, android-2.2-froyo

I'm looking to do something along the lines of the image below, with the "Snooze" button, but I'm trying to do it on Froyo and later. Is it possible to do this on pre 4.0 devices? I basically want to give the user the option to close my ongoing service from the notification bar.

[image: example of a notification button]

Comment: It is definitely possible because the default music player uses buttons in notifications, I would recommend looking through its source code and see what it does to create a notification

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android notification with buttons on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516722/android-notification-with-buttons-on-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NotificationCompat:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html

---

Add support libraries revision 10 more info http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: @MrMusAddict It will not give you buttons by the way, that is purely new Android.

Comment: Then what's Jake talking about here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NotificationCompat2

Comment: The screenshot above looks like an expanded notification, which as the docs say: `For example, action buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android 4.1. Action buttons depend on expanded notifications, which are only available in Android 4.1 and later.` A custom layout though, might work.