# How to tap and cancel progress bar from the Notification drawer like facebook's photo upload?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-progressbar, android-notification-bar

In my application I have a progress bar on Notification bar to indicate photo upload,I want to cancel the upload process when user Taps on the progressbar like facebook photo upload.How can I do that?? Any help is Appreciated.

My code to show Progress bar.

```
  mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager)    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ImageUploadActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Upload")
                        .setContentText("Upload in progress")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                new ImageUploadTask().execute();
 class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());



    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // Update progress
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
            // Sets the progress indicator completion percentage
            publishProgress(Math.min(i, 100));
            try {

                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.1.1.1/test/upload.php");

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();


          /* entity.addPart("uploaded_file", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    "myImage.jpg"));*/

                // String newFilename= filename.concat("file");
                // newFilename=filename+newFilename;

                entity.addPart("uploaded_file", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                        filename));
                //  Log.e(TAG, "Method invoked");
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                        localContext);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String aux = "";

                while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(aux);
                }

                String sResponse = builder.toString();


                return sResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
             /*   if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception Message 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;*/
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mBuilder.setContentText("Upload completed");
        // Removes the progress bar
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());


    }
   }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from api level 4.1 you can add action buttons to notification. To see the basics about notification check the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

And for some more help you can check this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959343/931982) and [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Comment: How to set click event for Progress bar notification??