# How to create clickable Textview in Android notification?

Tags: android, textview, android-notifications, clickable

I'm trying to create a clickable `TextView` in a notification.
I've created a layout with some `TextViews` and I use a `remoteView` to build the notification layout.
In the notification build method I use `setOnClickPendingIntent()` to assign a `Pending Intent` to the `TextView`.
When I actually try to click the `TextView` the whole notification is 'clicked' (as there is no clickable area besides the whole notification as one block).
I've tried removing the `pendingIntent` of the notification itself, but yet the whole notification is clicked (just does nothing).
What should be done to make these elements be clickable ?
Are only buttons be clickable in a notification ?

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479165/event-onclick-for-a-button-in-a-custom-notification

Comment: I've tried both `setOnClickPendingIntent` and `setPendingIntentTemplate`, all the other is the same, still nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mention android:clickable="true" for textviews in layout.

Like:

```
<TextView android:id="@id/tv1"
android:clickable="true"/>
```

By programmatically:

```
textview.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Now the notification is not clicked as a block, but the TextView click doesn't do anything