# How can I create a notification with an undo button like gmail?

Tags: android, android-notifications, undo

I want to implement a notification like this:

[image]

I know that I can use [custom layout notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification) and [set an onClickPendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830497/842697). But, is this the best option? If it is not, what is it? And if it is, how can I mimic the left square with the icon? Measures, color, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the best option. Use [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) to create your custom layout, and make sure to use [onClickPendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and not [setContentIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) for UNDO action. If you use the second approach notification bar gets minimized and that's not something you want if you want to seamlessly update the notification once again after user presses UNDO like Gmail does.

If you want to align your icon with non-custom notifications use following dimensions:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-content

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. What i did was in the PendingIntent activity/service create a new notification with the 'undo' button, etc.