# Android cancel notification

Tags: android

I have a background service running to get data. I check for new data and send status bar notification. Sending notification is part of the service. When user sees that notification, he logs on to the application and accepts it. That time I want to delete it from status bar. Can I do that ?

Comment: I believe that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android) post will answer your question. It discusses how to clear notifications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear a notification in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: remove notification from notification bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595232/android-remove-notification-from-notification-bar)

Comment: Show your code for notification

Answer (score 18):

```
if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE!=null) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(0);
    }
```

write the above code in the second class and create the notifications in the first class using the id 0.

Comment: If possible can you answer this question as well? It is not working for me on Android 10. [Click here for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61478154/5716010)