# How do I clear all notifications with separate app?

Tags: android, notificationmanager

Is it possible to make an icon on android that when clicked clears all notifications, e.g. SMS, email, missed calls etc?
I just want an icon on my home screen that clears all notifications. What coding would I use?

Comment: Thanks but from what I understand, that only applies if your own app had created a notification, then that would work.

Comment: Duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

Comment: @arshadkr No, not same here the question is to clear all the notification even it is not raised by you app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only remove a `Notification` that you raise yourself. You cannot remove a `Notification` raised by another application.

Answer (score 3):

`cancel(notificationID)` where you pass the notification id of the notification you have created

or else, you can clear all your notifications by `cancelAll()`.

***NOTE : *** Only notifications created by your application can be deleted. You **cannot** remove notifications created by some other application.