# NotificationListenerService: NullPointerException on getActiveNotifications

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm trying to implement the NotificationListenerService in my application according to this tutorial: http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html ,but i'm having a NullPointerException when calling getActiveNotifications.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1437)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)


at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNotificationsFromListener(INotificationManager.java:500)
at android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications(NotificationListenerService.java:149)
at com.rootsoft.rsnotificationservice.RSNotificationService.activeNot(RSNotificationService.java:85)
at com.rootsoft.rsnotificationservice.RSNotificationService.access$0(RSNotificationService.java:81)
at com.rootsoft.rsnotificationservice.RSNotificationService$1.onReceive(RSNotificationService.java:105)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:763)
... 9 more
```

I'm sending a broadcast to the service which should generate a list of all Notifications:

```
private void activeNot () {
    List l = new List();
    l.Initialize();

    for (StatusBarNotification sbn : getActiveNotifications() ) { <---- Error happens here
        l.Add(sbn);
    }

    Log.i("B4A", "List created.");


    }
}
```

Comment: @XverhelstX, I updated my answer to offer a much better solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT: I have since learned more about this and got it working!**

**NOTE: First, make sure you have enabled your app in the Notification Access settings pane of your Android device.**

I had the exact same problem until now. Turns out, overriding `onBind` is dangerous. If you do override `onBind`, you have to return the same IBinder that `super.onBind(intent)` returns. If you want to return your own custom binder, make sure you use a unique intent, and only return your custom binder when the custom intent is received.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals("custom_intent"))
    {
        return customBinder;
    }
    else
    {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }
}
```

The system calls onBind on your service, once you have granted it permission to read Notifications. If your onBind returns a custom binder to the system, the system will not give you the notifications, and could lead to Null Pointer or Security Exceptions.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hello, You mean u can avoid the exception of the question by add the method in your answer?

Comment: Yeah! We have to override onBind in a way that both the system and ourselves can use it. The system expects a specific Binder from dep inside Android, which we must provide. We expect our own custom binder, so we check for our custom intent and return our custom binder.

Comment: Today, I think your way not really exactly. You need [Enable Notification in Notification Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331482/getactivenotifications-always-null-when-using-notificationlistenerservice)

Comment: Great solution. An additional point... Android binds to your service on boot or when "Enable Notification" is first checked. I needed to uncheck/recheck the enable notification button after implementing your onBind solution for the binding to work properly.

Comment: Good solution! Fix my SecurityException issue.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call the getActiveNotification method in onCreate or onBind directly. Because the onBind will call the super.onBind to initialize, so you can use the handler to replace.
Here is my Demo:
https://github.com/yihongyuelan/NotificationListenerServiceDemo

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when I tried to start the service with startService(). I was wrong! The system does it for you when the user enables your app to listen for notifications