# Get unseen android notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a service that shows a notification PendingIntent each time it receives a new GCM message. The problem is that the GCM messages can be of different kinds. And if many notifications leave unread, I want not to show them separately but in groups like:

> you have 3 unread messages of type A
>
> you have 2 unread messages of type B
>
> you have 4 unread messages of type C

As far as I understand, to get this effect I need to have an access to unread/unseen notifications. Each time when I new notification comes I can check, if there is another unread message of this type, and then decide, whether I create a new notification or update an old one.

My question is: **is there a way to see, which notifications are unseen and get access to them**?

For any case this is my method to create a message; if an argument notificationId is 0 a new notification should be created. Else - updated.

```
 private int sendNotification(String msg, Integer notificationId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "sending message with text: "+msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Random random = new Random();
    int notification_id = notificationId==0?random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000:notificationId;

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.notification);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    // Send data to NotificationView Class
    intent.putExtra("text", msg);

    PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("escos")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pending);
    mBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notiftext, msg);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notifim, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification);

    return notification_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For different Notification strip (A, B, C etc.) in your status bar, use different **NOTIFICATION_ID** for building the Notification on basis of your `defined type` or `collapse_key` received from GCM.
2. For determining *unread* and *read* messages, use a local variable (counter) in Shared Preferences and increment it each time a specific type of Notification comes (on basis of defined type or collapse_key).
3. Then generate the Notification with that particular NOTIFICATION_ID as Notification with particular NOTIFICATION_ID can override each other. So You can override the previous Notification with Iterative Numbered text in New Notification.
4. As soon as user click on any Notification or particular Notification, clear the notification and reset the value of (counter) in Shared Preferences.

**Edit1 :** When you click on Notification with particular *Pending Intent*, then in that Activity use this code for removing all the Notifications generated from your app :

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
try {
        nMgr.cancelAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note : Do remember to add `Try-Catch` before you call `cancelAll()` as `cancelAll()` may not be supported by the device model and will generate

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial

error.

**Edit 2:**
You can also use `nMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);` to clear a specific notification, pass NOTIFICATION_ID to particular intent via extras and get the extras in that activity to cancel a particular notification.

And as you click on any notification it will be cleared from status bar unless you have not set `.setAutoCancel(false)` in your Notification Builder.

Comment: Thank you, it is actually the way how I planned to do it. But I dont' know how to realize 4. of your list.

Comment: @user2957954 please see `Edit1`.

Comment: it is still unclear how to handle if a notification was cleared or clicked.

Comment: @user2957954 please see `Edit2`.

Comment: I don't want to cancel notification programmatically. I want to understand if a user has read it or not. You wrote: "As soon as user click on any Notification or particular Notification, clear the notification and reset the value of (counter) in Shared Preferences." So my question is: **how can I catch this moment when a user clicks on a notifications or clears it**?

Comment: for that you can use `Notification Listener`, but its available only in API18+ and for that to you should ask for that permission to read your notification from `getActiveNotifications()` method. For more info see this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331482/getactivenotifications-always-null-when-using-notificationlistenerservice).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92877/discussion-between-vipul-asri-and-user2957954).