# Android: Notification listener issue

Tags: android

I created a class for listening to notifications:

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService




public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification) {
        Log.e(TAG, "notification posted" + "\n" + "\n");
        Notification postedNotification = statusBarNotification.getNotification();
        String packageName = statusBarNotification.getPackageName();
        if(postedNotification.tickerText == null || statusBarNotification.isOngoing() || !statusBarNotification.isClearable()) {
            return;
        }
        ...
```

The above is part of the code for receiving notifications, the issue is that the Log.e() statement is never triggered.

The following is in the AndroidManifest file where I declared the notification listener service.

```
<!-- NOTIFICATIONS -->
    <service android:name=".notifications_exp.NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I am a newbie programmer and have no idea why this happens. I've done quite a lot of searching but no luck. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you enabled your notification listener from your device's security settings?

Comment: Is onCreate called? Also, you shouldn't have onBind implemented.

Comment: `onCreate` is not called. And isn't `onBind` called when the user tick the notification access for the app? So I don't see any issues with that(?)

Comment: please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684738/notificationlistenerservice-nullpointerexception-on-getactivenotifications/21639879#21639879

Comment: well, even I removed the onBind implementation the program still doesn't receive any notifications

Comment: I finally got it working by only changing the package name -_-

Comment: Wait. I tested it once, it worked. Then I tried the second time, it doesn't!