# How to remove notification from notification bar programmatically in android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

How can one remove a notification from an application programmatically, which is called using Pending intent?

I have used to cancel notification using following method:

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(Display.this, TwoAlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Display.this, AlarmNumber, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
am.cancel(pi);
```

But problem is notification which fired already that are not removed from notification bar.

[image]

Comment: hi i don't know is it possible to remove notification programaticaly , but you can override the old notification with new one that's sure. if is it fullfil your requirement then i can post code for you here. plz reply

Comment: No, actually I have two different notifications and I am already cancelling notification.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Maybe try this :

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

OR, you can also do this to cancel all notifications in given context:

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

See this link to the documentation : [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int))

Comment: I don't see the point of `if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE != null)` because that is a String constant and will never be null.

Comment: you are right this test is useless, i don't know why i did it  (deleted it):/

Comment: @Matthieu it worked for be before 4 years... :) Not checked right now. Please let me know if it's not working in any case.

Comment: @JayeshSojitra I was just curious which of `cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)` or `cancelAll()` did the trick. In case your memory went back that far, it's not a big deal :)

Comment: @Matthieu In my case both worked. If you want to cancel specific one then use cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID) and if you want to cancel all notification then user cancelAll().

Comment: How can I get the `NOTIFICATION_ID`?

Comment: NOTIFICATION_ID is the id used at the creation of the notification, it's a parameter you can set at any value

Comment: Dear @An-droid I'm using your solution in react-native to remove all the popUps created by firebase it self and just show my own popup, but it doesn't remove the popup. any idea?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue the method would be `removeDeliveredNotification(notifId)` or `removeAllDeliveredNotifications` found in firebase documentation, you can find the opened issues on firebase github

Comment: if you start your service in forground then you must use stopForeground(true); for service
and then you can use above syntex.

Comment: @Niloufar almost one year after, but in the notification body you can set [a `priority` option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) that determines how the notification is displayed.

Answer (score 29):

I believe the most **RECENT** and **UPDATED** way of doing (Kotlin and Java) this should be done as:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)
```

Or to cancel all notifications is:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancelAll()
```

Made for AndroidX or Support Libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your solution works well as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Notifications remain visible until one of the following happens:

The user dismisses the notification either individually or by using "Clear All" (if the notification can be cleared).
The user clicks the notification, and you called setAutoCancel() when you created the notification.
You call cancel() for a specific notification ID. This method also deletes ongoing notifications.
You call cancelAll(), which removes all of the notifications you previously issued.
If you set a timeout when creating a notification using setTimeoutAfter(), the system cancels the notification after the specified duration elapses. If required, you can cancel a notification before the specified timeout duration elapse

```
public void cancelNotification() {

    String ns = NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All notifications (even other app notifications) can be removed via listening to 'NotificationListenerService' as mentioned in [NotificationListenerService Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation)

In the service you have to call `cancelAllNotifications()`.

The service has to be enabled for your application via ‘Apps & notifications’ -> ‘Special app access’ -> ‘Notifications access’.

Add to manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:label="Test App" android:name="com.test.NotificationListenerEx" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Then in code;

```
public class NotificationListenerEx extends NotificationListenerService {


public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationListenerEx.this.cancelAllNotifications();
    }
};


@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.app"));
}
```

After that use the broadcast receiver to trigger the clear all.

As per the above code to trigger the broadcast use;

```
getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.test.app"));
```

Comment: I don't know why you have posted this answer when it's already accepted https://stackoverflow.com/a/19268653/1404774.

Comment: Do you have any specific scenario in which above question is not working?

Comment: The above does not work for all notifications (All 'app' notifications). That removes only current app created notifications.

Comment: How to trigger? Send which broadcast? Can you please post also how to trigger it ?

Comment: As per the above code it would be; getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.test.app");

Answer (score 2):

For those who used (via subclass) the `Service` class and run it using:

```java
final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourNotificationService.class);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent);
```

you can close it like so:

```java
context.stopService(new Intent(context, YourNotificationService.class));
```