# How do I remove pushbots notifications while user is in the app?

Tags: android, pushbots

I am using pushbots with an android app. I have a custom broadcast receiver that handles notifications in the app. However, when I exit the app, all of the notifications are still there. How can I clear these notifications? I have tried the solutions on these questions: 
[How to clear a notification in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

[How to remove notification from notification bar programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268450/how-to-remove-notification-from-notification-bar-programmatically-in-android)

but Im still not having any luck. Any suggestions?

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("CHAT", "RECIEVED");
        Bundle notification = intent.getExtras();
        String type = notification.getString("type");

       //do some stuff here

        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //nMgr.cancel();
        nMgr.cancelAll();
        Log.d("CHAT", "CANCEL");
    }

};
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Ok Ive added the relevant code.

Comment: Let me ask you something, do you want to delete ALL the existing push notifications automatically when you kill the app or do you want to be able to delete them manually, I mean, with your finger?