# how to remove a persistent notification after setongoing(true)?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Here is the code that I'm using to create a notification in Android. This notification is shown as intended and isn't getting removed by swiping the notification.
But I'm unable to remove it programmatically. How should I remove it?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small)
                    .setContentTitle("persistent")
                    .setContentText("cant remove").setOngoing(true);
    mBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove notification from notification bar programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268450/how-to-remove-notification-from-notification-bar-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer there's a nice explanation on how to do it:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/19268653/3853450](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancel(int))

In your case should be something like this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(Constants.CHANNEL_ID);
```

Also, as given in the original answer:

[NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancel(int))

Comment: Thanks. I got it done with notificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build()); to send the notification  and removed it with the code you provided notificationManager.cancel(id);

Comment: Glad to help! :D