# How to remove notification from status bar when clicking the my footer icon

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

I want to remove the notification from status bar when clicking on footer icon. How to call this method outside the service class:

```
 mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Is there any other solution to remove notification by clicking the custom button?

Comment: isn`t it removed notification?

Comment: When notification comes, app is in foreground then I click my footer icon to open notification activity. At that time I need to remove the notification from status bar.

Comment: Refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268450/how-to-remove-notification-from-notification-bar-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the notification outside service class (such as activity using button click) in this way:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

You can see the detail of it at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Removing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setAutoCancel(true)` when building the notification.