# NotificationListenerService for APIs below 18?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, notificationservices

Is it anyhow possible to use NotificationListenerService for API levels older than 18. I couldn't find any info on that so I thought it's not possible but I just spotted a post on stackoverflow on which someone said it can be done. ([here Mr Nagendra said that they have provided support for older versions too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation)) I don't know how to ask him this questions directly so I'm asking it to everyone.

Please help me with this. AccessibilityService is causing a lot of trouble so I'm looking for alternatives. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any workaround for that?

Comment: @Forke No. Since I couldn't find any info on that, I don't think it is possible at this point of time.