# Check if user has granted NotificationListener access to my app

Tags: android, service, notifications, settings

I'm using this code to open Notification Listener Settings:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

I would like to check if the user has granted authorization to my app.
I already tried to check if my NotificationListenerService is running, but it seems that it gets halted and restarted by the system (even if I return START_STICKY).

Comment: I used this solution and it's works fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33871952/5053585

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was wrong, checking if service is running works:

```
    private boolean isNLServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
             if (NLService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                  return true;
             }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you uncheck the permission, the process keeps running. So this isn't bulletproof, but I haven't found another way.

Comment: If I uncheck the permission, my service gets destroyed. So the above answer works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 33):

The only correct way to do it is to check the secure settings:

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, YourNotificationListenerService.class);
String flat = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
final boolean enabled = flat != null && flat.contains(cn.flattenToString());
```

Comment: I really wanna give you a cookie! Gracias.

Comment: This works. You can check your AccessibilityService this way too, but by passing `"enabled_accessibility_services"` to `Settings.Secure.getString()`. Both strings are set as constants in Settings.Secure, but the one for notifications is hidden for some reason.

Comment: Not working. while it's already approved - this code returns false

Answer (score 7):

If you're using androidx you can use

```
NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(Context context)
```

to check if your listener is enabled. 
[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat#getenabledlistenerpackages)

Answer (score 0):

```
internal fun isNotificationServiceEnable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val myNotificationListenerComponentName = ComponentName(context, NotificationListener::class.java)
    val enabledListeners =
        Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners")

    if (enabledListeners.isEmpty()) return false

    return enabledListeners.split(":").map {
        ComponentName.unflattenFromString(it)
    }.any {componentName->
        myNotificationListenerComponentName == componentName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw this while browsing through the documentation inside android studio

> Read only list of the service components that the current user has
> explicitly allowed to  see all of the user's notifications, separated
> by ':'.

```
@hide
 @deprecated Use
 {@link NotificationManager#isNotificationListenerAccessGranted(ComponentName)}.
    @Deprecated
@UnsupportedAppUsage
@Readable
public static final String ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS = "enabled_notification_listeners";
```

Hence made this up and added to a publicly accessible class

```
 private fun notificationAccess(context: Context): Boolean {
        val mNotificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(NotificationListenerService.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "notificationAccess: >27 ")
            val status=mNotificationManager?.isNotificationListenerAccessGranted(
                ComponentName(
                    context,
                    NotificationService::class.java
                )
            )
            return status == true
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "notificationAccess: LESS THAN 27")
            try {

                val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
                val listeners =
                    Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners")
                return !(listeners == null || !listeners.contains(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                if (DEBUG) e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

I have tested for above API above 27 , test it for below 27 before you go to production

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted Answer gave me inspiration to come up with this answer:

```
class NotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {
    internal companion object {
        private var notRunning = true

        internal fun notRunning(): Boolean {
            return notRunning
        }
    }

    override fun onListenerDisconnected() {
        super.onListenerDisconnected()
        notRunning = true
    }

    override fun onListenerConnected() {
        super.onListenerConnected()
        notRunning = false
    }
}
```

Basically what this does is create a static function in the notification service that reports if the service is currently running using **onListenerConnected** and **onListenerDisconnected**.  **onListenerDisconnected** fires when the permission is turned off.

Then you just check **NotificationListener.notRunning()** to see if it's running. Further ActivityManager has been greatly hobbled in recent versions of Android, but this uses standard common things to work.

You could use **onListenerDisconnected** to fire off code in your app that gracefully handles the loss of notification access, or prompts the user.