# How to use notification lisenter?

Tags: android

I am creating a media player application. I want to show a notification on notification bar, with play, pause, forward, backward and close functionality. Notification is successfully displayed on Notification bar. but I am not able to give any click event on this..

Notification panel

```
public class NotificationPanel {

    Context mContext;
    NotificationManager mManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1234;
    ImageButton play_pause;

    public NotificationPanel(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext).
                setContentTitle("SONORE").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.dark_logo2).setOngoing(true);

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_bar_layout);

        setListeners(remoteViews);

        builder.setContent(remoteViews);

        mManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    }

    private void setListeners(RemoteViews remoteViews) {

        //listener to pause song
        Intent pause = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
        pause.putExtra("DO", "pause_play");
        PendingIntent playPausebtn = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 1, pause, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.fab_play, playPausebtn);

        //listener to remove notification bar
        Intent remove_notification = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
        remove_notification.putExtra("DO", "remove_notification");
        PendingIntent remove_notification_btn = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 2, remove_notification, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.remove_notification, remove_notification_btn);

        //listener to forward song
        Intent forward = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
        forward.putExtra("DO", "forward");
        PendingIntent forwardbtn = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 3, forward, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.forward, forwardbtn);

        //listener to backward song
        Intent backward = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
        forward.putExtra("DO", "backward");
        PendingIntent backbtn = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 4, backward, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.forward, backbtn);

    }

    public void notificationCancle() {
        mManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }

    public void changeToPlayIcon() {


    }
}
```

From this activity i am getting click lisenter event, and start a broadcast Manager to call my method from my main activity.

NotificationReturnSlot.activity

```
public class NotificationReturnSlot extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        int position;

        String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");
        if (action.equals("pause_play")) {
            position = 1;
            callMethodOfDrawerActivityFromNotificationBar(position);

        } else if (action.equals("remove_notification")) {
            position = 2;
            callMethodOfDrawerActivityFromNotificationBar(position);

        } else if (action.equals("forward")) {
            position = 3;
            callMethodOfDrawerActivityFromNotificationBar(position);

        } else if (action.equals("backward")) {
            position = 4;
            callMethodOfDrawerActivityFromNotificationBar(position);

        }


        finish();

    }

    public void callMethodOfDrawerActivityFromNotificationBar(int pos) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("notification-event");
        // add data
        intent.putExtra("notification", pos);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).

                sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

from MainActivity i am getting the broadcast event by the following way

```
     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            //Register Notification receiver
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mNotificationReceiver, new IntentFilter("notification-event"));
        }


     private BroadcastReceiver mNotificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int pos = intent.getIntExtra("notification", 0);

                switch (pos) {

                    case 0:
                        //do nothing
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (isSongPlaying()) {
                            pauseSong();
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
                        } else {
                            playSong();
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mPanel.notificationCancle();
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mService.playNextSong();
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        mService.playPreviousSong();
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mNotificationReceiver);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation

Comment: actually when i give any click on my notification layout, it did not call given method

Comment: @ajameswolf **This does not belong on Code Review.** Broken code is off-topic there, and questions containing it will be closed. **Please read the [help center there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).**

Comment: @ajameswolf and please stop recommending Code Review willy-nilly if you don't really understand what's on-topic there

Comment: @janos ok, what would you recommend in this case? it is too specific to be of any use? Similar to someone posting their coding homework on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my Answer. the problem is , i am calling remove broadcast from pause().. but it should be called after each action performed from Notification layout.