# Detect when Notification is clicked to send analytic's event

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

We have an app with GCM notifications working fine, we set a `PendingIntent` so the activity that we want is open when the notification is clicked. However, we need to send an event to `Google Analytics` each time that one notification (and there are different types of notifications) is clicked. How could we achieve this? I don't want to parse the intent in the activity, as I think that this would not be a good solution (we are using `TaskStackBuilder` so not always the same activity is open for the same notification), is there a receiver we can use to detect when the notification is clicked/open?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

put some `flag` variable on your notification intent.

```
intent.putExtra("notification","clicked");
```

Now check it in your `Activity`, whether Bundle is having "notification" key or not

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("notification"))
    //write your code for analytics
```

Comment: Hi, this is what we were trying to avoid, is there another option (such as a listener or receiver)?

Comment: there is a flaw: when you restart your activity (for example by changing the orientation) the onCreate will be called with the same intent and you will track the "open from notification" twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). It allows an application to receive information about notifications. You need to declare the service in your manifest file with the `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission and include an intent filter with the `SERVICE_INTERFACE` action to extend this class. See this [example](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example).

I also found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation) on how to implement NotificationListenerService using `TaskStackBuilder`. This might help.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem about using NotificationListenerService is that this is introduced on API 18, but we support API 16.