# Is there a way to read incoming notifications on an android phone from an application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When the phone receives the notification it will make an object in java called notification and store it in a database. How can I make it so that when a notification comes in the application can read that notification and then make the object?

Comment: This might be helpful https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications()

Comment: Thank you Kamran this really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access notifications, you can use the NotificationListenerService. The documents on this is located at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

For the implementation of this class, there has already been discussed within this link: [NotificationListenerService Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation) (See the accepted answer for a link to an example)

Comment: Thank you Joshua

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it acceptable.