# How to clear a notification (not issued by you) from drop down programatically?

Tags: android

What I am trying to do is to devlop an app that clears notification when you shake it. I can find ways to cancel notification that has been previously sent by you but not all notifications. Please tell me how to solve this problem. Also, tell me what permissions to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android

Comment: @nrofis Thanks man. I didn't see that fragment earlier.