# How do I check if some notification message is already read or deleted from action bar by user?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm trying to create a stack notification in the action bar.
I want to update the counter (++counter) when a new notification arrives and show the counter value in the action bar.
like this:
"2 new messages"

My problem is that when the user has already clicked on the notification message then it is deleted from the actionBar. Then later if a new notification appears I want my counter to reset and again show in the action bar the sum of messages that have not been read.

How can I know if the notification has already been removed/read from the action bar?

Answer (score 0):

This gets easier if you decide to reset the unread message counter when the user reads the messages. Now, you need to delete the old notification and make a new one, with the updated count.

That is, there's no need to check, just make a new notification and dismiss the old one:
[How to clear a notification in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

Comment: If I'm delete the notification where to reset the counter? I didn't understood how can I know if the user reads them for remove them?

Comment: You assume that the message is read when the user visits the screen (Activity) containing the messages. You reset the counter in _onResume()_. And if that Activity is on screen, you do not need to add notifications.

Comment: But I need that if the user is delete the message and doesn't visit in the activity the counter is still reset.

Comment: Then reset it when the user deletes the message, too. (Well, in this case it is more sensible to reset the counter if *either* the notification message is deleted *or* the activity containing the messages is launched -- I mean, it's meaningful to place both cases in the same class)

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting the latest APIs (21 or above?)
Check for NotificationListenerService from Android Developers.

There are two methods, onNotificationPosted() and onNotificationRemoved()

Now, use a `Set<notificationID>` mySet. In onNotificationPosted(), call `mySet.add()` to add all the notifications posted.

In  onNotificationRemoved(), call mySet.remove()

At any point when you want to check if notification is avaialble in notification bar, call `mySet.contains()`

Comment: How can I use Set<notificationID>? where to put this code?

Comment: Set<T> where T is Generics Type.

So use a Set like HashSet etc. or any other Collections that you might be interested in. In onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) method, keep on add the notification id that was posted i.e. something like mySet.add(sbn.getId())


Look here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Comment: Do you mean that I need to create some database to save the notification that I notifyed? and then I can  access to each of them?

Comment: I need to create class and extand NotificationListenerService, then in the code can I check if they read?

Comment: @Toda please read that link.
This is a listener service that will help you to "listen" to the notifications that are posted in your notification bar, either from your own app or some other app like whatsapp.
Now whenever user will read/delete etc. the notification, you will be notified again because of this service.

Comment: can you give me an example link? I didn't understood how to use this. thank you!

Comment: I don't targeting the latest APIs, what can I do?