# Remove notification icon when user open app through launcher Icon

Tags: android, push-notification, sms, launcher

Hello I am developing an app in which i want to give push notifications to user when Sms receives. Now the problem is that the notification icon still does not remove when app open by user through launcher icon
Here is my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon);
            notify.setContentTitle(title);
            notify.setContentText(msgBody);
            notify.setAutoCancel(true);
            Notification notification = new Notification();
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            //notify.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notify.setLights(Color.GREEN, 2000, 2000);
            notify.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            notificationIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intentt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
            notify.setContentIntent(intentt);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notify.build());
```

I tried like this too:

```
notificationManager.cancel(0);
```

and also tried this:

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

but both these doesnot work. They doesnot allow notification to occur. Maybe they are cancelling the push notification before its creation.
Please Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear a notification in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

Comment: Did you try to put the cancellation code in onCreate?

Comment: @MorZa No sir, should i need too? but if i write that and if there is no notification and i open my app then maybe it will give null exception? please explain

Comment: In my code I get the intent and then check it's not null: Intent intent = getIntent(); if (intent != null){...}. It make sense to me to put it in onCreate or onResume because the user opens the app when he/she press the notification and these methods are called.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just cancel all the notifications inside the main Activity's `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

That is because you asked

> Remove notification icon when user open app through launcher Icon

But best way is to put it in `onResume()` so that when the app is in background you want to show the notification and remove it when user brings it to foreground.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

Comment: I think `onStart` will be the best choice here. p.s. for Kotlin: `(getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as? NotificationManager)?.cancelAll()`