# Hide in-app notifications from Android notifications history

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm doing in-app notifications on Android.
I'm using `NotificationCompat.Builder` and `NotificationManager` to do it.
I set my notifications priority to `PRIORITY_HIGH` to display them as a popup.

But the notification is displayed in the Android notifications history. How to prevent this ?

Comment: What is "the Android notifications history"?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a notification you call

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

I would suggest calling this code after you create the pop up so that there is no notification left in the tray. I found this code here: [How to clear a notification in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

Comment: It works but on the device I tried it, the notification goes out really quicker. Is there a way to extend the duration of the notification ?